# How to Scrape Scheduled WebEx Meetings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

How can I list out the scheduled WebEx meetings?
Here are the WebElements

Element:

```
<div class="meeting_list"><div role="region" aria-label="My Webex Meetings list" class="meeting_list_content" style=""><!----> <!----> <!----> <div role="grid" aria-relevant="additions removals" class="m_list" style=""><div class="m_list_item m_list_item_0"><div class="col col_1 col_0_1"><span class="avatar_img avatar_small" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://mirantis.webex.com/avatarservice/v1/users/520902917/avatars/390b91c0-571c-4889-a708-57c891b44315?siteurl=mirantis&amp;size=64&quot;);"><img src="https://mirantis.webex.com/avatarservice/v1/users/520902917/avatars/390b91c0-571c-4889-a708-57c891b44315?siteurl=mirantis&amp;size=64" alt="Avatar Picture"></span></div> <div class="col col_2 col_0_2"><div><div class="list_t">
    11:00 AM - 12:00 PM
  </div> <div class="list_st">Wed, Apr 8</div></div></div> <div class="col col_3 col_0_3"><div class="list_t"><div class="meeting_topic meetings"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="#3446655 Instance hangs on migration, virsh commands timedout" class="">
          #3446655 Instance hangs on migration, virsh commands timedout&nbsp;
        </a></div> <div class="back meeting_topic_column"><!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <span><!----></span></div></div> <div class="list_st">Mirantis Operations&nbsp;</div></div> <div class="col col_4 col_0_4"><span class="list_btn"><button type="button" class="el-button el-button--success" aria-label="Press enter to Start the meeting."><!----><!----><span>Start</span></button></span></div></div><div class="m_list_item m_list_item_1"><div class="col col_1 col_1_1"><span class="avatar_img avatar_small" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://mirantis.webex.com/avatarservice/v1/users/520902917/avatars/390b91c0-571c-4889-a708-57c891b44315?siteurl=mirantis&amp;size=64&quot;);"><img src="https://mirantis.webex.com/avatarservice/v1/users/520902917/avatars/390b91c0-571c-4889-a708-57c891b44315?siteurl=mirantis&amp;size=64" alt="Avatar Picture"></span></div> <div class="col col_2 col_1_2"><div><div class="list_t">
    12:00 PM - 1:00 PM
  </div> <div class="list_st">Wed, Apr 8</div></div></div> <div class="col col_3 col_1_3"><div class="list_t"><div class="meeting_topic meetings"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="00122550 EMEA Scanner is not scanning properly" class="">
          00122550 EMEA Scanner is not scanning properly&nbsp;
        </a></div> <div class="back meeting_topic_column"><!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <span><!----></span></div></div> <div class="list_st">Mirantis Operations&nbsp;</div></div> <div class="col col_4 col_1_4"><span class="list_btn"><button type="button" class="el-button el-button--success" aria-label="Press enter to Start the meeting."><!----><!----><span>Start</span></button></span></div></div> <div class="infinite-loading-container"><div style="display: none;"><i class="loading-spiral"></i></div> <div class="infinite-status-prompt" style="display: none;"><span></span></div> <div class="infinite-status-prompt" style=""><span></span></div></div></div> <div><!----> <div><!----></div></div><div class="el-loading-mask" style="display: none;"><div class="el-loading-spinner"><svg viewBox="25 25 50 50" class="circular"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke-width="2" stroke="#D1D3D7" fill="none"></circle><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" class="path"></circle></svg><!----></div></div></div></div>
```

As you can clearly see this lists out the availble meetings in HTML. 
However, I would just like to get a clean list of this.
Here is the defined XPATH:

```
//*[@id="main_content"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div
```

Is there any way I can scrape out this information in python?
I have been able to get a successful request, but documentation seems scarce to work with GET requests to WebEx.

Here is my code that has been able to get me a successful authentication at the very least.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import logging
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
import subprocess
import lxml
import time
import unittest
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from lxml import html

with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

requests.get('https://mirantis.webex.com', 
              auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config['username']['password']))

# GET Page Source
page = requests.get('https://mirantis.webex.com/webappng/sites/mirantis/meeting/home')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# GET Meetings
meetings = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div')
meetings
```

I would like to list this out in a dataframe probably with Pandas:

[image]

However, what I get is nothing...it's just empty.
Normally I would expect to see results, but it's just nothing:

```
>>> page = requests.get('https://mirantis.webex.com/webappng/sites/mirantis/dashboard?siteurl=mirantis')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
>>> meetings = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div')
>>> meetings
[]
```

When I use `page.content` I get an HTML body, am I scraping this wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there's no Javascript involved when the HTML is loading?
If you check 'view page source' via chrome, do you still see this element? if not, it means it's rendered by JS, which isn't visible to a static python requests.

try using selenium or a similar webdriver

Comment: HI unfortunately I didn't want to try Selenium because it is such a pain. I cannot even login via WebEx, I don't know why. If you want I will open up another question in regards to how to do that, but I keep getting trace backs when I try to login. @MenyIssakov

Comment: @MenyIssakov I made a separate question here as it is blocker for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104794/how-to-login-to-webex-platform-with-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, try using selenium to extract this data:

use `pip` to install it via `pip install selenium`

You'll also need to download chrome (if that's your choice of driver) from 
`https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads` and adjust the code snippet I've added, to point to the correct chrome driver binary

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

url = "https://mirantis.webex.com/webappng/sites/mirantis/dashboard?siteurl=mirantis"
chrome_driver_path = "<path_to_chrome_driver>"
xpath_pattern = '//*[@id="main_content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div'


def find_meetings(driver, pattern):
    meetings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(pattern)
    #do something here

driver = Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
try:
    driver.get(url)
    find_meetings(driver, xpath_pattern)
finally:
    driver.close()
```