# How to Login to WebEx Platform with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't login to the WebEx Platform, and I need to be able to login to WebEx to scrape the meetings scheduled for the week. I keep getting tracebacks, but I can't even `send.keys()` methods to the perspective login form on the login container. The main thing is I am having an issue with just autneticating. I need to be able to login  to be able to parse and see the current weeks schedule.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITAdminInfra/blob/master/Integrations/WebEx/list_meetings.py

The code that is not working is:

```py
#browser.switchTo.frame("topframeset")
#browser.switch_to.frame("main")

# Authentication
# Credentials NEEDS UNIT TEST
username = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))
#utente = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-username").send_keys('user@gestione.eu')
password = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-password')))
username.send_keys(config['user']['username'])
password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])

# Authentication submit.click()
# For XPATH = //*[@id='mwx-btn-logon']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mwx-btn-logon']")))
element.click();
print("Logging into Mirantis WebEx System!")
```

Here is the page source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow'>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'>
<meta name='slack-app-id' content='A5P5FDK33'>
<meta name="description" content="15"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicont29.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<TITLE>MIRANTIS INC WebEx Enterprise Site</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">


<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Cisco Webex Meetings" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Simple, modern video meetings for the global workforce. Join from anywhere, including your desktop, browser, mobile device, or video room device." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mirantis.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/html/img/webexball_opengraph.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Cisco Webex Site" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://mirantis.webex.com/" />
<script language="JavaScript">
function setCookie(name,value) 
{ 
    var Days = 30; 
    var exp = new Date(); 
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days*24*60*60*1000); 
    document.cookie = name + "="+ escape (value) + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString()+";path=/"; 
} 


function getCookie(Name)
{


    var search = Name + "=";
    if (document.cookie.length > 0)
    { // if there are any cookies
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1)
        { // if cookie exists
            offset += search.length; // set index of beginning of value
             end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset); // set index of end of cookie value
             if (end == -1)
                 end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
}
  //default page should never load inside of another frame
  if (top.location != self.location) {
    top.location = self.location;
  }



var oneDay= 1*24*60*60*1000;
var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setTime (expDate.getTime() + oneDay);
var cookieExpires = expDate.toGMTString();

document.cookie="verifyCookie=test; expires="+cookieExpires

if (document.cookie.length<=0 || getCookie("verifyCookie") == null){
    window.open('https://mirantis.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/jsp/common/warningnote.jsp?siteurl=mirantis', 'Warning', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=auto,resizable=yes,width=300,height=220');
}

document.cookie="verifyCookie=CLEAR; expires=Sun, 09-Nov-97 01:00:00 GMT";
try{
    if('&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("meetinginfo")!=-1||( '&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("e.do")!=-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("siteurl")!=-1)&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("landingpage.do")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("mainframe.do")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("mywebex")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299'.indexOf("frame.do")==-1){
        setCookie("jmtlogloginclicktime",new Date().getTime());
    }
}catch(ex){

}


    var dom = document.getElementById ? 1 : 0;
    var ns4 = (document.layers && !dom ) ? 1 : 0;
    // do for ns4 resize problem
    function mm_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
        if (init==true) {
            with (navigator) {
                if ((appName=="Netscape") && (parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
                    document.mm_pgW=innerWidth;
                    document.mm_pgH=innerHeight;
                    onresize=mm_reloadPage;
                }
            }
        } else if (innerWidth!=document.mm_pgW || innerHeight!=document.mm_pgH) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    if(ns4)
        mm_reloadPage(true);


document.cookie = "screenWidth=" + screen.width + "; path=/; secure";

function closeWindow() {
    window.close(opener=0);
}
function submitChildFrame(){
    window.frames["mainFrame"].postChildForm("\x2fmw3300\x2fmywebex\x2flogin\x2flogin.do\x3fsiteurl\x3dmirantis\x26viewFrom\x3dmodern\x26login_return_url\x3dhttps\x253A\x252F\x252Fmirantis.webex.com\x252Fwebappng\x252Fsites\x252Fmirantis\x252Fdashboard\x253Fsiteurl\x253Dmirantis\x26rnd\x3d0.4396788955860299");
}
function submitChildFrame4Header(){
    window.frames["header"].postChildForm4Logout();
}
</script>


<base href="https://mirantis.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/jsp/frame/mywebex.jsp">
</HEAD>

<!-- CDN Host: akamaicdn.webex.com Status: OK -->

<FRAMESET id="topframeset" BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 ROWS="131,*,0">
    <FRAME SCROLLING="auto"  NORESIZE NAME="header" SRC="/mw3300/mywebex/header.do?service=1&siteurl=mirantis&viewFrom=modern&rnd=0.738597730304002" title="The header frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">


        <FRAME SCROLLING="auto" NORESIZE NAME="mainFrame" SRC="&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;login&#47;login.do&#63;siteurl&#61;mirantis&#38;viewFrom&#61;modern&#38;login_return_url&#61;https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmirantis.webex.com&#37;2Fwebappng&#37;2Fsites&#37;2Fmirantis&#37;2Fdashboard&#37;3Fsiteurl&#37;3Dmirantis&#38;rnd&#61;0.4396788955860299" target="_top" title="The content frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">

    <FRAME SCROLLING="no"  NORESIZE NAME="rotation" SRC="/mw3300/mywebex/frame/clientpath.do?siteurl=mirantis" title="The clientPath frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">
</FRAMESET>



<noframes>
<h2>Sorry.</h2>
&nbsp;<p><b>Webex requires the use of Netscape Navigator 4.0, Internet Explorer 4.0 or better.</b></p>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried switching to the frame itself, I have never encountered a situation, where I have not been able to login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is present inside an `iframe` name `mainFrame` you need to switch it first.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and iframe name

**Code here:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Chrome("path here")
url = "https://mirantis.webex.com"
browser.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='guest_signin_button']")))
element.click();
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"mainFrame")))
username = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))
username.send_keys("user@abc.com")
password = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-password')))
password.send_keys("userabc")
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @KubduK this helped  million.